# Bootstrap 3 in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use bootstrap in my symfony project . But when I configure json file through this error. However I have included

```
new Braincrafted\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\BraincraftedBootstrapBundle()
```

I have looked up from [here](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started.html#installation)

error:

```html
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception


                                                                               
  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:    
  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Braincrafted\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\BraincraftedBo  
  otstrapBundle' not found in /home/kanat/Public/bootstrap/app/AppKernel.php
```

I have looked up from [here](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started.html#installation)

Comment: Please edit your question to show your `composer.json`.

Comment: it could be a folder permissions issue, i enbounter this like 5million times a day. also you could just use bootstrap instead of a whole bundle, its easier

Answer (score 0):

like the error says, its having touble clearing the cache, that could be a directory permission issue,set the folder permissions to read write and execute and then try to clear cache again, (in linux it would be `sudo chmod -R 777 *`)